# CK Editor custom plugin to create a button

Tags: drupal, ckeditor

I have been trying to create a custom plugin to create a 'h1' button for the toolbar. Here is my plugin code -

```
"use strict";

var pluginName = 'customButtons';

CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'customButtons', {
    icons: 'h1_btn', // If you wish to have an icon...

    init: function( editor ) {
        // Tagname which you'd like to apply.
        var tag = 'h1';
            // Note: that we're reusing.
            //style = new CKEDITOR.style( editor.config[ 'format_' + tag ] );
        var style = new CKEDITOR.style( { element: 'h1' } );

        // Creates a command for our plugin, here command will apply style. All the logic is
        // inside CKEDITOR.styleCommand#exec function so we don't need to implement anything.
        editor.addCommand( pluginName, new CKEDITOR.styleCommand( style ) );

        // This part will provide toolbar button highlighting in editor.
        editor.attachStyleStateChange( style, function( state ) {
            !editor.readOnly && editor.getCommand( pluginName ).setState( state );
        } );

        // This will add button to the toolbar.
        editor.ui.addButton( 'h1', {
            label: 'Click to apply format',
            command: 'customButtons',
            toolbar: 'insert'
        } );
    }
} );
```

I added the plugin to config.js as well.
Any idea why this isn't working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I figured out the answer. But letting the question be, in case some stumbles over with the same problem. 
It turned out that ckeditor.editor.php has a bug (wrong directory name for plugin). I changed it back to the directory name in the folder structure and voila, it worked !!